# C++ - Adding item to QListWidget from QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt5

Hello I am trying to add items to a QListWidget from a QPushButton. Both the QListWidget and QPushButton are added as individual widgets inside of a QGraphicsScene. I want the effect of a box that fills with text lines

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    QGraphicsView view;

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 1200, 1200, &view);

    scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::gray);

    view.setScene(scene);

    QPushButton *PushButton1;
    PushButton1 = new QPushButton();
    PushButton1->setGeometry(QRect(19, 20, 154, 4));

    QListWidget *ListWidget;
    ListWidget = new QListWidget;

    scene->addWidget(ListWidget);
    scene->addWidget(PushButton1);

    QObject::connect(PushButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()),&w, SLOT(handleClick(*QListWidget)));

    view.show();

    return a.exec();
```

}

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::handleClick(QListWidget *List)
{
    int test;

    List->addItem("TESTING");

    //QApplication::quit();

}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QListWidget>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;


    private slots:


    public slots:

        void handleClick(QListWidget *List);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

This code compiles fine. How I get the following error in the console when the application is running

```
QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::handleClick(*ListWidget) in ..\MenuTest\main.cpp:48
```

Can someone help me do this? I've seen several tutorials but it's using the designer to make the GUI and I'd like to know how to do it in code without using designer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your slot accepts QListWidget but you're connecting with ListWidget as the parameter, the signature has to be an exact match due to the way signals and slots work in Qt.

Put handleClick under `public slots:` and change this line:

```
QObject::connect(PushButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()),&w, SLOT(handleClick(*ListWidget)));
```

To this:

```
QObject::connect(PushButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()),&w, SLOT(handleClick(*QListWidget)));
```

*Update:*

I see I missed a key point, the signatures have to match, as in parameter to parameter, so the line up there will not work.

To fix this remove the parameter completely, since PushButton1 can't send it automatically.

```
QObject::connect(PushButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()),&w, SLOT(handleClick()));
```

Also remove it here:

```
void MainWindow::handleClick()
```

To access the QListWidget you'll have to reference it directly, either by passing it to MainWindow's constructor or iterating the window's controls.

Comment: hey voodoo thanks for the help. tried what u said and still the same error though. I've edited the original post to the changes made. Still compiles fine, but when running the app the console still returns the same slot not found error

Comment: hey voodoo thanks again for the help. I'm a bit new to how Qt works. I also tried making QListWidget *ListWidget a global but that didn't work for several reasons. Would u mind doing a brief pseudo code explaining what you've mentioned or linking a tutorial to this method ?

Comment: Does "pass it to main window's constructor" mean to take all the code currently in my main thread and put it inside of ui(new Ui::MainWindow) ?

Comment: Well, you need a major restructuring of your code, why is there a MainWindow at all when you're using `view.show();` as your main window? You need to move everything to do with widget construction inside `MainWindow`'s constructor and use member variables to hold your controls. You can then access the controls from slots like normal.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on signals and slots by the way: http://openbooks.sourceforge.net/books/kde20devel/ch03lev1sec3.html

Comment: Thanks voodoo, that worked. Qt is great for graphics but they should have compiler side checking to warn about passing arguments in slots